# How to send a list of object from my MainPage.xaml to another page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

When navigating to another page how can i make my list of object available to another page.

for example in my mainpage.xaml

```
var data2 = from query in document.Descendants("weather")
           select new Forecast
           {
                date = (string)query.Element("date"),
                tempMaxC = (string)query.Element("tempMaxC"),
                tempMinC = (string)query.Element("tempMinC"),
                weatherIconUrl = (string)query.Element("weatherIconUrl"),
            };

forecasts = data2.ToList<Forecast>();
....
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WeatherInfoPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

and then in my other class, i want to make it available so that i can use it like this

```
private void AddPageItem(List<Forecast> forecasts)
{
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this may help you

//using   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State to store the list//

PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] = lstpro.SelectedItems;
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/res.xaml", UriKind.Relative))

And in The Second Page

private IList iList1;

//In The onNavigatedTo Event assign the stored list to the variable//

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)

```
{
     var i= PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"];

     //convert object to list//
     iList1 = (IList) i ; 
     lstpro.ItemsSource = iList1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global variable which you place in App.xaml.cs:

```
//In App.xaml.cs
public static List<Forecast> SelectedForecasts = null;
```

The variable will be available in the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

In general I use an additional class implemented with a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern. In this class I store every data that needs to be exchanged between pages. Basically it's the same approach as Jon mentioned, but I like to keep my App.xaml.cs clean. So you can access your data from everywhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this but none of them is truely elegant. The main issue being to handle tombstoning scenarios : To be restored entirely, your page has to be able to retrieve its input list even if the App has just been re-activated (and all previous states coming from previous navigation erased...)

- You can serialize your list with your own custom format and add it to the end of your Uri. The downside being that you have to parse and deserialize the Uri by yourself (Maybe this way looks more natural for simple and small amount of data like an id for instance).

To navigate to the next page :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WeatherInfoPage.xaml?data1;data2;serializeddata", UriKind.Relative));
```

To retrieve data in the next page, you would have to parse and to deserialize it from the current Uri :

```
 Uri currentUri = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.CurrentSource;
```

- You can also store your list into a dedicated variable located in [AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or [PhoneApplicationService.Current.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) before navigating and retrieving it in the new page. Perharps it could be interesting to create a dedicated class to do this job. It could be a centralized place to push and retrieve parameters, to ensure parameters uniqueness, to manage parameters lifetime and so on... It could also be applied to the first proposal.
- Finally, if your list is persisted somewhere (a file, embedded database), you can just pass an id to the next page (using previous proposals) and retrieve the corresponding list by querying it from your persisted source.

In both cases, you will be able to pass your list to the next page and handle tombstoning scenarios.